# Solution to equilibrium convection-diffusion-reaction equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am trying to solve the following BVP:

$-\Delta u + b\cdot \nabla u + u = k$

On the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions where $b$ is a constant vector field, and $k$ is a positive constant.

I would at least like a push in the right direction here if not a detailed explanation.  I tried separation of variables-that didn't work.  Is there a closed-form Green's function?  Is there just a way to intuitively solve it by inspection?